# Scipy ndimage median_filter origin

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, median, ndimage

I have a binary array, say, `a = np.random.binomial(n=1, p=1/2, size=(9, 9))`. I perform median filtering on it using a `3 x 3` kernel on it, like say, `b = nd.median_filter(a, 3)`. I would expect that this should perform median filter based on the pixel and its eight neighbours. However, I am not sure about the placement of the kernel. The [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.median_filter.html) says,

> origin : scalar, optional.
>
> ```
> The origin parameter controls the placement of the filter. Default 0.0.
> ```

If the default were zero, it should be taking the current pixel and the `3 x 3` grid to the right and bottom, no? Shouldn't the default be the center of the `footprint`? Which in our `3 x 3` example would correspond to `(1, 1)` as opposed to `(0, 0)`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

origin says it accepts only a scalar, but for me it also accepts array-like input as also the case for the [scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve.html) function. Passing 0 is indeed the center of the footprint. Origin's value is relative to the center. With a 3x3 footprint, you can specify values -1.0 to 1.0. Here are some examples. Notice in the example with origin not specified that the filter is centered as expected.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage

a= np.zeros((5, 5))
a[1:4, 1:4] = np.arange(3*3).reshape((3, 3))

default_out = scipy.ndimage.median_filter(a, size=(3, 3))
shift_pos_x = scipy.ndimage.median_filter(a, size=(3, 3), origin=(0, 1))
shift_neg_x = scipy.ndimage.median_filter(a, size=(3, 3), origin=(0, -1))

print(a)
print(default_out)
print(shift_pos_x)
print(shift_neg_x)
```

Output:

Input Array:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  2.  0.]
 [ 0.  3.  4.  5.  0.]
 [ 0.  6.  7.  8.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Centered Output:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  4.  2.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  4.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Shifted To Right Output:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  4.  2.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  4.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Shifted To Left Output:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  4.  2.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  4.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```